# Pandas: merge_asof with conditions from other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a toy example as follows
[image]

I would like to merge the actions column in rules to the original df.  Merging conditions are the following.

1. (value >= lower) & (value < upper)
2. date in df must merge with the nearest previous date in rules

The expected output is shown in the above figure.  Here is the df and rules

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2022-05-15", "2022-05-20", "2022-05-25", "2022-05-30"],
                   "values": [10, 20, 30, 80]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

rules = pd.DataFrame({"lower": [0, 25, 50, 75, 0],
                      "upper": [25, 50, 75, float("inf"), 25],
                      "actions": [5, 10, 15, 20, 8],
                      "date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-05-18"]})
rules["date"] = pd.to_datetime(rules["date"])
```

May I have suggestions about effective method to do this?

I'm trying to solve this problem in an alternative way using pandasql because thus join can be done easily in SQL.  Here is my code

```
from pandasql import sqldf

sql = """SELECT DISTINCT on (df.date)
             df.date,
             df.values,
             rules.actions
         FROM df
         LEFT JOIN rules
         ON (df.date > rules.date) AND (df.values >= rules.lower) AND (df.values < rules.upper)
         ORDER BY df.date, rules.date DESC"""

pysqldf = lambda x: sqldf(x)
pysqldf(sql)
```

Even though the sql statement is working in postgres, it does not work when I run with pandasql.  I got the following error.

```
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "on": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT DISTINCT on (df.date)
             df.date,
             df.values,
             rules.actions
         FROM df
         LEFT JOIN rules
         ON (df.date > rules.date) AND (df.values >= rules.lower) AND (df.values < rules.upper)
         ORDER BY df.date, rules.date DESC]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Did I overlook something?

Comment: distinct on is supported only by Postgres; you need to rewrite your code using a windows function to get top or last value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), and after the merge, you can do a groupby to get the minimum rows:

```py
# install from dev 
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor
import pandas as pd

(df
.astype({'values':float})
.conditional_join(
    rules.astype({'lower':float}), 
    # pass the conditions as a variable arguments of tuples 
    ('values', 'lower', '>='), 
    ('values', 'upper', '<'), 
    ('date', 'date', '>'),
    # select required columns with df_columns, and right_columns
    df_columns = ['date','values'], 
    right_columns={'actions':'actions', 'date':'date_right'})
# get the difference and keep the smallest days
.assign(dff = lambda df: df.date.sub(df.date_right))
.sort_values(['date', 'dff'])
.drop(columns = ['dff', 'date_right'])
.groupby('date', sort = False, as_index = False)
.nth(0)
)

        date  values  actions
0 2022-05-15    10.0        5
3 2022-05-20    20.0        8
4 2022-05-25    30.0       10
5 2022-05-30    80.0       20
```